# Index was outside the bounds of the array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array" on this line, what's wrong?

```
Kort[x, y] = Sort[x] + Valor[y] + " ";
```

Below is the complete code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace uppgift_13
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            string[,] Kort = new string[4,13];
            string[] Valor = new string[13];
            string[] Sort = new string[4];
            int x, y;


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Valor[1] = "2";
                Valor[2] = "3";
                Valor[3] = "4";
                Valor[4] = "5";
                Valor[5] = "6";
                Valor[6] = "7";
                Valor[7] = "8";
                Valor[8] = "9";
                Valor[9] = "10";
                Valor[10] = "Knekt";
                Valor[11] = "Dam";
                Valor[12] = "Kung";
                Valor[13] = "Ess";

                Sort[1] = "H";
                Sort[2] = "R";
                Sort[3] = "S";
                Sort[4] = "K";
            }


            private void LaddaKort()
            {
                for (this.x = 1; this.x <= 4; this.x++)
                {
                    for (this.y = 1; this.y <= 13; this.y++)
                    {
                        Kort[x, y] = Sort[x] + Valor[y] + " ";
                    }
                }
            }

            private void SkrivKort()
            {
                for (this.x = 1; this.x <= 4; this.x++)
                {
                    for (this.y = 1; this.y <= 13; this.y++)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(Kort[x, y]);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LaddaKort();
                SkrivKort();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use Array initializers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx) to declare and initialize the arrays in 1 line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start your array accesses from 0, and not 1

So, change to this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Valor[0] = "2";
                Valor[1] = "3";
                Valor[2] = "4";
                Valor[3] = "5";
                Valor[4] = "6";
                Valor[5] = "7";
                Valor[6] = "8";
                Valor[7] = "9";
                Valor[8] = "10";
                Valor[9] = "Knekt";
                Valor[10] = "Dam";
                Valor[11] = "Kung";
                Valor[12] = "Ess";

                Sort[0] = "H";
                Sort[1] = "R";
                Sort[2] = "S";
                Sort[3] = "K";
            }
```

Also, start any of your loops at 0, instead of 1. And make the conditional be less than the length, not until equal. More like:

```
for (int i=0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
```

Comment: You should also mention this about his loop bounds since that's where he will be looking. They are 1-based as well... 
edit: I see you updated the post :)

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing that out, realized it after I had hit submit, unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

in C# arrays are zero-based...

look at what Kevek answered you plus:

this:

```
for (this.x = 1; this.x <= 4; this.x++)
{
  for (this.y = 1; this.y <= 13; this.y++)
  ...
```

should be:

```
for (this.x = 0; this.x < 4; this.x++)
{
  for (this.y = 0; this.y < 13; this.y++)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort is an array 0..3, and Valor is 0..12. So you cannot use Sort[4] and Valor[13].