# Index was outside the bounds of the array in lambda expressions linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to check whether the array has minimum two counts in .net,I am getting Index was outside the bounds of the array for the following line

```
var resValues = sites.ToDictionary(x => x.Split(',')[2].Replace("test=", ""), 
       x => GetTestCodeename(x.Split(',')[2].Replace("test=", ""), 
          GetTestCode(x.Split(',')[2].Replace("test=", "").Split('_')[1])));
```

where resValues are of count 1200, so  i cannot think of storing in some variable..I want to do for all these 1200 values in single Linq code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index was outside the bounds of the array (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337464/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-c)

Comment: Given the name of the variable `x` and the presence of the Linq tag, I'll say that the expression is like `x => GetTestCode(...)`, so it is a little more difficult than normal to do the checks...

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: _I want to do for all these 1200 values in single Linq code_ iow: I want code that is really hard to read and impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put some checks here and there :-)

```
var resValues = (from x in sites
                 let sp1 = x.Split(',')
                 where sp1.Length > 2
                 let rep = sp1[2].Replace("test=", "")
                 let sp2 = rep.Split('_')
                 where sp2.Length > 1
                 select new
                 {
                     Key = rep,
                     Value = GetTestCodeename(rep, GetTestCode(sp2[1]))
                 }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Note the use of the keyword `let` to create a variable inside the LINQ expression, then the creation of a new temporary anonymous object containing the `Key` and `Value`, then the creation of the `Dictionary<,>` starting from this object.

I'm skipping all the elements that can't be totally splitted through the two `where`.

Comment: infact it is for 1200 collections,how to do that,i edited my question, i need it in lambda expression rather than anonymous methods

Answer (score 1):

a few modifications should help you avoid the index out of bounds exception:

```
var result = sites.Select(s => s.Split(','))
                  .Where(s => s.Length > 2)
                  .Select(s => s[2].Replace("test=", ""))
                  .ToDictionary(s => s,
                        s => GetTestCodeename(s,
                                 GetTestCode(s.IndexOf('_') != -1 ?
                                        s.Split('_')[1] : string.Empty)));
```

or if you don't want to pass an empty string in the case where `s.IndexOf('_') != -1`  returns false then you can go with this approach:

```
var result = sites.Select(s => s.Split(','))
                  .Where(s => s.Length > 2)
                  .Select(s => s[2].Replace("test=", ""))
                  .Where(s => s.IndexOf('_') != -1)
                  .ToDictionary(s => s,
                        s => GetTestCodeename(s,
                             GetTestCode(s.Split('_')[1])));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(a[1]==null)
   {
     var hasCountTwo= false;
   }
   else{
     var hasCountTwo = true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid an out of bounds exception and null values altogether you can take a  monadic approach with `SelectMany`. Here instead of nulls you will have an empty sequence on which any LINQ function returning enumerable will work without throwing an exception just propagating this empty sequence. `Skip` and `Take` also doesn't check for length and return an empty enumerable or some subsequence in case the collection is too short.

```
var resValues = sites
    .Where(s => s != null)
    .SelectMany(s => s
        .Split(',')
        .Skip(2)
        .Take(1) 
        .Select(a => a.Replace("test=", ""))
        .SelectMany(a => a
            .Split('_')
            .Skip(1)
            .Take(1)
            .Select(b => new
            {
                TestCodeName = GetTestCodeName(a),
                TestCode = GetTestCode(a, b)
            })))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.TestCodeName, p => p.TestCode);
```

Note that this will ignore all the sites where it couldn't take the values `Split(',')[2]` or `Split('_')[1]` in your example.